# Multiple extension of layout in twig/php

Tags: php, twig

I have a problem figuring out how to solve the following issue with Twig templates

I have a system where two parts wants to change blocks in the layout without know each other. The idea of my templates are

```
main.twig
<html><body>
{% block a %}{% endblock %}
{% block b %}{% endblock %}
</body></html>

replacea.twig
{% extends "main.twig" %}
{% block a %}hello{% endblock %}

replaceb.twig
{% extends "main.twig" %}
{% block b %}world{% endblock %}
```

My problem is that I do not know how to achieve this, as the places where I call replacea and replaceb only shares a "viewengine" so I am able to collect all render calls and bulk them.

My first idea to solve this was to extend a variable, say "layout", but then when I call render layout would be replaced with the same in all templates and not with "replacea.twig" in replaceb and with "main.twig" in replacea.

Hope you understand my problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use "Use" - pun not intended! :-)

```
main.twig
<html><body>
{% block a %}{% endblock %}
{% block b %}{% endblock %}
</body></html>

replacea.twig
{% block a %}hello{% endblock %}

replaceb.twig
{% extends "main.twig" %}
{% use "replacea.html" %}
{% block b %}world{% endblock %}
```

Check out the documentation:
https://twig.symfony.com/doc/tags/use.html

Comment: Well, that requires replaceb to know about replacea, but I made it such that instead of "replacea.html" I use a dynamic variable and know it works! - THANKS!